# Can't Obtain Apple Provisioning through Paid Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, provisioning-profile, apple-developer-account

**Attempt on Windows PC**

I am using Xamarin and want to log into my Apple developer account on PC Visual Studio to test app on iPhone. Apple developer account is registered into its annual membership. However, the provisioning process is horribly challenging:

As you can see from the picture below. The automatic provisioning failed. When I view the details of my account, none of the provisioning profile is loaded --> can't do manual provision. The Role was originally "Xcode_free_user" and I changed the json file so now looks like "Agent" but no help.
[image]

The log reports the following: the core message is "Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AppleServerException: This request is forbidden for security reasons: Authentication Error."

> DateTime=2022-06-27T00:44:07.0554913Z: 06/27/2022 00:44:07Z
> Xamarin.Messaging.Client.AgentConsoleRunner{Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.IDBLocalAgent}
> Information: 0 : XMA-Initialized-3d502c86: 06/27/2022 00:44:07Z
> DateTime=2022-06-27T00:44:07.0584849Z: 06/27/2022 00:44:07Z Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.GetMobileDeviceConfigurationMessageHandler
> Information: 0 : Apple Support - iTunes installed: 'False',
> Installation type: 'None': 06/27/2022 00:44:07Z
> DateTime=2022-06-27T00:44:07.1043626Z: 06/27/2022 00:44:07Z Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient Error: 0 : An error occurred
> on client IDBLocal while executing a reply for topic
> xvs/idb/check-provisioning-status
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AppleServerException: This request is
> forbidden for security reasons: Authentication Error. Xcode 7.3 or
> later is required to continue developing with your Apple ID.    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning.AppleDeveloperPortal.HandleServerError(JObject
> serverJson) in
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/External/maciostools/Xamarin.MacDev.AppleSigning/AppleDeveloperPortal/AppleDeveloperPortal.cs:line
> 1212

[image]

---

**Attempt on Mac**

I decided to change approach by loading my Xamarin code to Visual Studio on Mac instead, but the Apple developer account login page for Visual Studio on Mac doesn't even have the button for selecting the phone number for 2-factor authentication...
[image]

Any amount of help would be appreciated.

Comment: *Visual Studio Code on Mac"* - There are TWO different versions of VS on Mac. One has "Code" in the name, the other does not. If you are trying to do in Code, instead do it in [VS 2022 on mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/).

Comment: Please don't change the question in the middle. Now the question has a title about developing on Windows. And the first half is about that. Then you switch to Mac. This will be unclear in the future - the purpose of StackOverflow is to create a **long-term repository of useful questions and answers.** Next time, **create a new question** when you change to a different approach. (Too late to do that now, because the only answer given is for developing on Mac.) **I've edited title and question to clarify.**

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve for the suggestions! Your edit makes the question much clearer now. "VS code on Mac" was a typo and it was actually "VS" only, not the code.

Comment: If you want to do manual provision, you could refer to [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-load-Apple-certificates/1692185#T-N1703589).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this stuff is hard. Everytime I have to deal with it is a struggle.

This is how I made it work on my machine.  There might be easier ways, so I'll be watching this question with interest.

I recommend you first make Xcode work.   You need to have Xcode as well as Visual Studio.

Launch Xcode then choose Xcode / Preferences, then choose Accounts.  Make that page happy. That's probably going to involve downloading a code signing or developer certificate (for you), and a provisioning profile (for your app) from developer.apple.com and importing it into Keychain.

Then close Xcode and open it again and check the accounts page.

Once Xcode is happy, go to Visual Studio on the Mac.

Importantly, on my Mac, the Apple IDs list *in Visual Studio* is empty.  This install runs my app on an iPhone attached to the Mac (I just had to fire it up again to validate that). We don't build the app for release on this machine, we use an Azure Devops Pipeline for that, for reasons that made sense at the time. But it sounds like you're not looking to build your release app at this stage.

But you *do* need to tell Visual Studio to use your provisioning profile:

Right click on your iOS project, Options / iOS Bundle Signing (under Build).  Choose a Signing Identity.  Ours has "Automatic" for provisioning profile.

That was enough to make it work, for us.

Note that because it's in the `.csproj` file, that gets checked into your source code repo (just the name of the signing identity, not the actual identity itself).  So if there's more than just you working on the app, everyone has to have the same provisioning profile on their machine.  If you want to do that, then you need to export the **private key** from Keychain Access for the provisioning file, then copy that across to the other machine and install it.  Make sure you zap it securely from any media you put it on.

I have a note in my wiki from 09 March 2022 saying "Automatic Provisioning doesn't work" but even I'd take that with a grain of salt, and I wrote it (plus there's a new version of Visual Studio for the Mac that's been released since then).

Comment: Thank you for such a warmth and thoughtful answer! I successfully used the Apple iD to sign into my Mac Visual Studio and Xcode. I went into the solution option tab and under build tab there is only option “General" and "Configurations". I didn't find the access for iOS Bundle Signing for visual studio 2022.

Comment: Moreover, I follow the tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos but when I click "view details" under the developer account setting, the VS said I need to "download certificates and provisioning profiles directly from the website". But I don't know how to further progress afterward.

Comment: I attempted to directly run the code on Visual Studio for Mac on iPhone and the app was successfully deployed in the phone but the app keeps crashing and quit whenever I attempted to open the app.